# Excel 2010 - copy data from one sheet to another, with error message if not found

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel spreadsheet with hotel information in one sheet, and booking information in another.

The hotel sheet looks like this. HotelID is Column A, HotelName is B.

```
HotelID HotelName
H001     Hilton
H002     Royal
```

The booking sheet looks like this. BookingID is Column A, and so on.

```
BookingID CustomerID HotelID HotelName
B001      C001       H001
B002      C003       H003
```

I want to copy the HotelName across from the hotel sheet to the booking sheet. I know I can use VLOOKUP for this, but I need to show "hotel not known" or similar if the HotelID doesn't exist and this is the part I'm stuck on.

I can reference cells in another sheet, I just can't work out how to get VLOOKUP to show "hotel not known". I think I need another function wrapping the VLOOKUP, but not sure which one.

Comment: Do you just need to wrap it in `IFERROR()`? `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([whatever]),"hotel not known")`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, just copy and paste it:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('hotel information'!B:B,MATCH('booking information'!C2,'hotel information'!A:A,0)),"hotel not known")
```

Hope it helps!